# Recent advances in the use of the spectra of kernel integrals following Yoshua Bengio's 2004 paper that links kernel PCA and spectral clustering?

Tags: machine-learning, kernel-trick, kernel-smoothing, spectral-analysis

In Yoshua Belgio's 2003 technical report http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~lisa/pointeurs/TR1232.pdf, and subsequent 2004 paper http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~lisa/pointeurs/bengio_eigenfunctions_nc_2004.pdf, he showed that both spectral clustering and kernel PCA are special cases of learning eigenfunctions of the kernel integral operator: $K[f](x):=\int_{\mathbb{R}^p}k(x,y)f(y)dP(y)$ where $P$ is a probability measure on $\mathbb{R}^p$. In the second link (the paper), he also mentions and proves certain results on the convergence of the eigenspectra of random matrices $[k(X_i,X_j)]_{n \times n}$ to the eigenspectrum of the kernel integral operator $K$. Note that, here $X_1,...X_n$ are i.i.d. random variables from an unknown distribution.

In the **discussion and open questions sections** of both the report and the paper, he talks about **using a smoother distribution than the empirical distribution to approximate the eigenspectrum of the kernel integral operator $K$ defined above. He also poses the question of possible applicability of this kind of smoother approximation**. See pp. 28 of the paper (second link), point 1.

**I'd like to know if there's some recent developments or advancements, research wprks regarding using a smoother approximation to kernel integral operator?**